# How do you get bar index if you know the time in pine-script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500)
timeframe = input.timeframe(defval = '240')
leftBars  = input.int(defval = 2, title = "Left Bars", minval = 1)
rightBars  = input.int(defval = 2, title = "Right Bars", minval = 1)

get_ph()=>
    float ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
    phtimestart = ph ? time[rightBars] : na
    phtimeend = ph ? time[rightBars - 1] : na
    barindex = ph ? bar_index[rightBars] : na

    [ph, phtimestart, phtimeend, barindex]

// get if there if Pivot High/low and their start/end times
[ph, phtimestart, phtimeend, barindex] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, get_ph(), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

// phtimestart -> is the time where my target 4h bar sarted
// barindex -> is the bar index of the bar in 4h timeframe
```

How can I find out the bar_index of a bar on any timeframe knowing the phtimestart?
Drawing a line there works just fine but I can't calculate the bar_index on lower timeframe at that point in time.

I would need the index of the bar in the image on the lower tf:
[image: Test Indicator]

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
(time - phtimestart) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
```